# Google maps API containslocation on a search change icon color

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get my google map to change the color of the search icon based on the location the result is located in.

[API info for places-searchbox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

[API for poly-containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)

I am trying to combine these so that the searched location will have the icon change based on the location of the results.
The second part will be to have the icon change colors when dragged in or out of the polygon.

Instead of having it change when clicked on the map
I would like to change the color of the search icon when generated...
just not sure where my code will go... something like this:

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
     var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.2631)
  ];
  var theTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords
  });
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    var result;
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, theTriangle)) {
      result = 'red';
    } else {
      result = 'green';
    }

    var circle = {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: result,
      fillOpacity: .2,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      strokeWeight: .5,
      scale: 10
    };

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map,
      icon: circle
    })
  });


  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding-left: 14px;  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
        width: 401px;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mLLepk9q/

Comment: Note that you should post your code _in the question itself_ not just a link to a fiddle or other external site. From [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on sqlfiddle.com or jsbin.com) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.".  Added your code for you.

Comment: thank you for updating this for me geocodezip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSFiddle is messy.  So ill try and explain:

1. Set the **map property** on your triangle polygon to show it for a start.
2. To change the marker colour when you drop it in the polygon: Make
   your marker draggable look at this example:
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations

   Add a dragend event to your marker when when that fires - check if
   its inside the polygon:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "dragend", function(event) {
    // check if marker is in polygon and change color or marker
   });
   ```
3. As for Search result - once the results come back change marker/color based on location as desired.

Answer (score 2):

1. add the geometry library

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

2. check to see if each marker is in the polygon and change its icon if it is:

```
var alternateIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png";
if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.getPosition(), theTriangle)) 
  marker.setIcon(alternateIcon);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j62tqar3/)

working code snippet:

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.
var theTriangle;
var map;

function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.2631)
  ];
  theTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    map: map,
    clickable: false
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    var result;
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, theTriangle)) {
      result = 'red';
    } else {
      result = 'green';
    }

    var circle = {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: result,
      fillOpacity: .2,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      strokeWeight: .5,
      scale: 10
    };

    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map,
      icon: circle
    })
  });


  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (input));

  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var alternateIcon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png";
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.getPosition(), theTriangle)) marker.setIcon(alternateIcon);

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
  width: 401px;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```